# Should variables passed into constructor be available as properties?

Tags: c#, oop

my boss insisting on the following rule: all variables passed into constructor should be available through a read-only property.

I don't see a real reason why this should be true, because class should do that it's supposed to do and not to provide theirs structure to others. I understand that sometime it's useful, but it isn't general rule.

Are my thoughts correct? Am I missing something? Anyone can add more arguments or oppose to that?

Example of rule:

```
 public class MyClass
 {
      public MyClass(ISomeProvider someProvider)
      {
          SomeProvider = someProvider;
      }
      public ISomeProvider SomeProvider { get; private set; }
      public void DoSomeWork()
      {
          ...
      }
 }
```

Thank you.

Comment: if it doesn't *serve a stated purpose*, I would be dubious of following **any** rule like that

Comment: Is the restriction there for the benefit of the testing framework?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally I would say no... I never believe there is one rule that fits all. If the parameters are used internally to the class then there is no need to expose them.

If you passed a 'raw' string password into an encryption class you wouldn't expect the raw string to be accessible throughout the lifetime of the object, in fact doing so may present a security risk.

On the flip side though, sometimes you have to follow the standards set out by the team/manager. If you think the principle is wrong discuss this detailing the arguments for/against the idea.

Answer (score 1):

It **may** be applied like a rule on some specific part of the some specific projects (should say, sounds very strange design, but..), but it's never, ever can be a generic rule in software design even in the domain of one single project.

Answer (score 1):

The rule decided by your boss can help in debugging to know the properties of object. It's not a rule, you can treat it as design pattern created by your project manager.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private ISomeProvider someProvider;

    public ISomeProvider SomeProvider
    {
        get
        {
            //logic here 
            return this._someProvider;
        }
    }

    public MyClass(ISomeProvider someProvider)
    {
        this._someProvider = someProvider;
    }

    public void DoSomeWork()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure that's a sort of design pattern